# MVC Action receives wrong parameter via Jquery AJAX request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

I am trying to be familiar with ASP MVC by working on simple MVC project.

But there is a problem I can't figure out.

On certain event, AJAX request is sent to one action taking IDictionary type parameter.

But the received parameter contains controller name, action name and language instead of data specified in Jquery AJAX call.

Please take a look at below code.

RouterConfig

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
  routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

  routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Language",
    url: "{lang}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new {controller = "Login", action="Index", id=UrlParameter.Optional},
    constraints: new {lang = @"en|fr"}
  );

  routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Login", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional, lang = "en" }
  );
}
```

Action

```
public ActionResult ApproveUsers(IDictionary<string, string> CheckedUsers)
{
  return View();
}
```

JQuery

```
  $('#confirmModal #action').click(function () {
  var cb = {};
  var data = {};
  $("input:checkbox:checked").each(function () {
    var key = $(this).attr('value');
    var val = $(this).closest('tr').next().find('table').attr('id');
    cb[key] = val;

  });
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '/AdminHome/ApproveUsers',
    dataType: "html",
    contentType: 'application/json',
    data : JSON.stringify(cb),
    success: function (result) {
        alert("success");
    },
    error: function(result) {
        alert("failed");
    }
  });
});
```

So when button is clicked all the checked checkbox data are sent to ApproveUsers action as keyvaluepair.

But no matter what the cb object in Jquery contains, the IDictionary parameter in ApproveUsers action only is like below

```
 [0] {[ contoller, AdminHome ]}
 [1] {[ action, ApproveUsers ]}
 [2] {[ lang, en]}
```

This seems like there is something wrong with RouteConfig. But I don't know why.

I would really appreciate if anyone can help me know why and fix this issue.

Thanks,

Comment: What steps have you done to verify that the request being sent is sending the data that you expect it should be sending?

Comment: For the test, I put hard coded string for the key and value in JQuery event like cb["firstTestKey"]="firstTestValue" and could see the received parameter by putting break point in the action. No matter what I put in the cb object, the parameter always contained controller name, action name, and lang only.

Comment: you don't appear to be naming your parameter to pass to the controller.  I expect to see something similar to `data: {CheckedUsers: cb}`

Comment: `dataType: "html"` should be `dataType: "json"` if you're passing json

Comment: The `DefaultModelBinder` does not work well with  a `Dictionary`. Use a `List<T>` where `T` contains 2 `string` properties for the values you need. (but at the very least you would have needed `data : JSON.stringify({ CheckedUsers: cb }),` - and there is nothing wrong with the route definitions)

Comment: @Steve Yes, you are right. Missing parameter name was the problem. Many thanks guys

Answer (score 0):

I found what's wrong with my code.

I was missing the parameter name in AJAX call so parameter biding failed.

As Steve said, code should be like below.

```
 data : JSON.stringify(CheckedUsers:cb)
```